Implementing Constraints in Pyomo to Prevent Variable Equality
I am working on a Pyomo optimization model where matrix M represents stoichiometric coefficients. I  need to implement constraints to ensure that certain variables are not equal to each other. Specifically, in this case I tried to implement a Big-M method to enforce this, but I'm encountering issues with my current implementation. The system runs but tells me that the 1 solution candidate is infeasible.
Current Implementation
In my model, I have defined reaction coefficients (model.M) and a binary variable (model.binary_diff) to help with the Big-M constraints. However, the following constraints are not working as expected:
    model.n_coeffs = pyomo.RangeSet(0, 2 * N - 1)  # Reaction coefficients
    model.reactions = pyomo.RangeSet(0, 1)  # Reaction index
...
    model.M = pyomo.Var(model.reactions, model.n_coeffs, domain=pyomo.NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(0, O * S), initialize={(r, c): 0 for r in model.reactions for c in model.n_coeffs})
...
    model.binary_diff = pyomo.Var(model.reactions, model.n_species, domain=pyomo.Binary)
    model.limits = pyomo.ConstraintList()
...
    for i in model.n_species:
        # The binary variable will control whether the difference between model.M[ri, i + N] and model.M[ri, i] is enforced
        model.limits.add(model.M[ri, i + N] - model.M[ri, i] >= 1 - BigM * model.binary_diff[ri, i])
        model.limits.add(model.M[ri, i + N] - model.M[ri, i] <= -1 + BigM * (1 - model.binary_diff[ri, i]))

Issue
These constraints are intended to prevent the variables model.M[ri, i + N] and model.M[ri, i] from being equal. However, I get things like:
  [linear] <lc18>:  -8<b207>[B] (+0) -<i211>[I] (+0) +<i215>[I] (+0) <= -1;
;
violation: right hand side is violated by 1
all 1 solutions given by solution candidate storage are infeasible

in the output.
Question:
What modifications can I make to ensure that these constraints function as intended?
I have tried other things aside from the big-M approach, like:

model.limits.add(model.M[ri, i + N] != model.M[ri, i])
model.limits.add(
sum(abs(model.M[ri, i + N] - model.M[ri, i]) for i in model.n_species) >= 1
)
and they didn't work either.

Context:

The number of species (N) is set to 2, and the reaction order (O) is 2.
I tried setting BigM to 1000,100,10,...
The constraint I'm trying to set should prevent the first N elements and the latter N elements, for each row, from being the same:

for N = 3, if M[ri] = [0,1,0,1,0,0] is fine because [0,1,0] != [1,0,0]
for N = 3, if M[ri] = [0,1,0,0,1,0] should not happen because [0,1,0] = [0,1,0]



Any guidance or suggestions on how to implement this constraint effectively would be greatly appreciated!

Your post neglects a key piece of information:  What type of variable is M?  And how many M[ . , i] need to be "different" and what is the exact definition of "different"?

I might suggest that you edit your post and show a couple small examples for what you consider to be acceptable values for an array of M and that might give clarity to your question

@AirSquid thanks for the suggestion. I edited it, the idea is that M has 2N elements per row, and that the first N elements cannot be the same as the latter N elements for each row.

That is still not well specified.  It isn't clear what you mean by "the first N elements cannot be the same as the latter N elements".  For example, if N=3: [1,2,3,1,2,4], [1,1,1,2,2,2], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,3,2,1].  There's several cases there which illustrate the point.  All different, any different, different sequence, etc. etc.

@AirSquid I have now modified it to clear that up. Hope the examples help.
